# How to call function one times with current state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => () => UpdateAPI.update(posts), []);

  const handleSubmit = () => setPosts([...posts, { name: 'johny', surname: 'bravo' }]);
```

Hello, I have a table and users can add new data. I want to call my service when user leaving the page. So, I need to use unmount effect but it takes my initial state([]). If i add my state to second argument, the service will be called every time the state changes. I want to call service one times with my current state.

Comment: could you try to console.log(posts) before updateapi ?

Answer (score 1):

try this.

```
useEffect(() => {
//you mount effect

return () => {
 // your unmount effect, the return is called when the component unmounts
UpdateAPI.update(posts) // here I suppose that your posts are is the current data.
}

},[]);
```

if you need further explanation I suggest you read this
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason is that your `posts` are stuck in the closure, also they may not be there by the time of unmount. You can try using `useRef`

```
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

  const postsRef = useRef(posts);
  postsRef.current = posts;

  useEffect(() => () => UpdateAPI.update(postsRef.current), []);

  const handleSubmit = () => setPosts([...posts, { name: 'johny', surname: 'bravo' }]);
```